# Difference between Object and %Object{}

Tags: elixir, ecto

I wonder what is the difference between those two objects -> Object and %Object{}.

1)

```
  def get_parents() do
    Object
    |> select([m], {m.id, m.name})
    |> where([m], is_nil(m.parent_id))
    |> Repo.all()
  end
```

2. ```
   def get_parents() do
     %Object{}
     |> select([m], {m.id, m.name})
     |> where([m], is_nil(m.parent_id))
     |> Repo.all()
   end
   ```

I will be grateful for explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object` is an atom, representing [module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html).
`%Object{}` is a [struct](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2) object declared in `Object` module.

[`Ecto.Query.select/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#select/3) has clauses for both atom and struct passed as the first argument, basically, when the atom is passed, the default struct is created and passed further like shown below (the real implementation is way more complicated)

```elixir
def select(module, binding, expr) when is_atom(module),
  do: select(%module{}, binding, expr)
```

---

I would strongly encourage you to learn language basics before turning yourself into `Ecto`.